# How can I detect if a VM is crashed?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I installed 4 Ubuntu virtual machines (in VirtualBox which itself is hosted by Ubuntu).
I am allowed to used only one of them at once. I can use any other available VM only if the first one crashes (for whatever the reason is).

How can I detect if a VM is crashed using any programming language, comman line or any available method ? I want to automate the detection of the crash of a given VM in order to launch an other one automatically too.

Comment: Maybe try to explain the situation a little more in detail... does Ubuntu crash? Does VirtualBox crash? What can you see in the logs? Maybe you could do with a nagios monitoring server that sends out automatic messages... can't really tell if that would be a solution with the (lack of) information you're giving.

Comment: I mean if one of my VMs crashes, not the host. I will read about Nagios monitoring, i never heard about it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show all running virtual machines we can issue the following command on the host:

```
VBoxManage list runningvms
```

If we only want to display the state of a running machine (`running` vs `paused`) we can also read from a long output of this command, e.g. like follows

```
VBoxManage list --long runningvms | grep State
```

In case your guest OS is freezing on the crash you encounter but still running this command will however still show the machine as alive. Only if the VM completeley aborts we will not get a result.

Alternatively we may also try if we can ping the VM in case it is connected by network.